# Solve the initial value problem: $\frac{dy}{dx} = e^{x+y}$, given $y(0)=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I have attempted the question several times so far, and I have always reached the same answer that differs from the solution, any advice would help greatly!

**My attempt**

$$\frac{dy}{e^y} = e^x dx$$

Taking the integral, I got $$-e^{-y} = e^x + C.$$

Solving for $y$, I got $$y=-\ln(C-e^x).$$

After subbing in $y(0)=0$, I got $$0=-\ln(C-1)$$ and solving for $C$, I got $$C=2.$$

Thus, I got $$y=-\ln(2-e^x).$$
However, the solutions have $y=-\ln(1-e^x)$ as the answer. Have I done something wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you're correct!

Comment: You can see that the solution must have a problem since (according to the solution), you have $y(0) = -\ln(1 - e^0) = - \ln(0) \color{red}{\neq} 0.$ :)

Comment: You're correct!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, and their solution is wrong. Their solution indeed satisfies the differential equation - however, ${y(0)}$ for their solution ${\neq 0}$. In fact, ${y(x=0)}$ doesn't even exist for their solution, since the function blows up to infinity

Answer (score 1):

You are not wrong, here is another solution.

Rewrite to $e^{-y}dy=e^xdx$ then integrate from $x=0$ to $x=a$ to obtain
$$\int_0^{y(a)}e^{-y}dy=\int_0^ae^xdx$$
which gives
$$1-e^{-y(a)}=e^a-1$$
that after rearrangement gives
$$e^{-y(a)}=2-e^a$$
take logarithm on both sides and then multiply by $-1$ to obtain
$$y(a)=-\ln(2-e^a)$$
Substitute a with x to get your answer.